# VPN between Ubuntu server (14.04.1 LTS ) AND Cisco ASA 5510

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, openswan

I have an Ubuntu server (14.04.1 LTS ) that should connect to a Cisco ASA 5510 (Adaptive Security Appliance). I have tried - to use [Racoon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/racoon.8.html) without any success. Not even phase 1 is successful.

The topology looks like this;

[image]

The Cisco ASA 5510 dictates the following settings should be used (just a policy by the owners);

**Phase 1:**

```
Authentication Method: PSK
Encryption Scheme: IKE
Diffie-Hellman Group: Group 2
Encryption Algorithm: 3DES
Hashing Algorithm: MD5
Main or Aggressive Mode: Main Mode
Lifetime (for renegotiation): 28800 seconds
```

**Phase 2**

```
Encapsulation (ESP or AH): ESP
Encryption Algorithm: 3DES
Authentication Algorithm: MD5
Perfect Forward Secrecy: NO PFS
Lifetime (for renegotiation): 3600
Lifesize in KB (for renegotiation): 4608000 kilobytes
```

I have all IP addresses, and encryption domains for both ends. In my end, it's another server where all the "important" stuff happens. This one running the VPN actually acts as my gateway.

I have already invested some days trying to use [Racoon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/racoon.8.html) unsuccessfully. I hereby ask for your help great people. I need to know a quick install, configure and use GUI tool to help me connect to this Cisco ASA 5510 device from the Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS server.

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally managed to set up the tunnel. I can now ping the host behind the Cisco ASA device. Originally, I wanted a GUI tool, but I realized the digitalocean VPS console access has a wrong mouse pointer so I kept running into problems trying to use GUI tools like vpnc in the method described [here](https://my.hostvpn.com/knowledgebase/11/L2TPorIPSec-Connection-from-Ubuntu-Desktop-1204.html).
I ended up using openswan. Here is how.

1. Install openswan.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openswan
   ```
2. Enable kernel IP packet forwarding and disable ICP redirects

   ```
   echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   echo "net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1" |  tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
   ```

   ```
   sysctl -p
   ```
3. Configure Openswan. The file is `/etc/ipsec.conf` Here's how mine ended up looking like;

   ```
   config setup
           dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
           nat_traversal=yes
   virtual_private=%v4:!,%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
           oe=off
           protostack=netkey
           plutostderrlog=/var/log/openswan.log
           force_keepalive=yes
           keep_alive=60
   conn myVpnConn
       authby=secret
       pfs=no
       auto=start
       keyingtries=%forever
       ikelifetime=8h
       keylife=1h
       ike=3des-md5;modp1024
       phase2alg=3des-md5
       type=tunnel
       leftsourceip=202.x.x.101    #my_local_ip aka encryption domain
       left=202.x.x.100
       aggrmode=no
       right=41.x.x.x
       rightsourceip=172.x.x.x
       dpddelay=10
       dpdtimeout=3600
       dpdaction=restart
   ```
4. Start ipsec/openswan

   `service ipsec start`

That was it in a short summary.

I stumbled upon well written articles showing how to configure openswan vpn.

1. [Remy van Elst's post](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/IPSEC_L2TP_vpn_with_Ubuntu_14.04.html)
2. [Gregg's post](http://www.knaddison.com/technology/setting-openswan-site-site-vpn-ubuntu-12-04-and-cisco-asa-5520)