# VPN between Ubuntu server AND Cisco device

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco, openswan

I have an ubuntu server that should connect to a Cisco device. I've googled and found out this could be accomplished using Openswan and also I've followed the steps from a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546677/vpn-between-ubuntu-server-14-04-1-lts-and-cisco-asa-5510/550212#550212?newreg=0b971dc6ea194c0eb2316ff772f38672), but I've difficulties pinging the internal hosts of the other network. It's important to notice that makes my scenario different from the question's is that my VPN device (Ubuntu) is also the host of all other private services, that is I only have one Ubuntu device and it runs services that need to access the vendor's internal devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer in this post: [What is an IPsec Site-to-Site VPN?](http://thejimmahknows.com/site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-using-openswan-and-cisco-asa-9-13/)